# TikZ: How to fill a circle of a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way in the syntax
`\draw[densely dashed] (M) -- (33:\r) circle[radius=5mm];`
to say that the small circle should be filled (gets the key 'fill')?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{3} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\footnotesize,
]
\fill[] circle(1.5pt) coordinate[label=$M$](M);
\draw[] circle[radius=\r];

\draw[densely dashed] (M) -- (33:\r) circle[radius=5mm, fill] coordinate[label=below:$$] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the `fill` option to the `\draw` command: `\draw[densely dashed, fill=yellow] (M) -- (33:\r) circle[radius=5mm];`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Silly question. ;)

Comment: No, it is a valid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Jasper Habicht comment with some small changes of your code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\footnotesize,
]
\fill circle(1.5pt) coordinate[label=$M$](M);
\draw circle[radius=\r];

\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{33}    % <---
\draw[densely dashed, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1]  % <---
    (\angle:\r) coordinate[label={[anchor=180+\angle]:$A$}] (aux) circle[radius=5mm] -- (M); % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]